# Golang binary on Heroku

Tags: heroku, go

I've made a Golang application and I've no problem getting it to work on Heroku using the buildpack but now I would like to distribute the compiled program to others without the source code.

Is it possible to get the binary working on Heroku without the source code or does Heroku need the source code to create its own compiled version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Heroku buildpack for Go](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-go) doesn't do anything special: it just [calls out to the Go tool](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-go/blob/master/bin/compile) to compile the binary based on whether you use godeps or not.

Just call `go build` in the directory of your `package main` or `go build repo.com/you/yourmainpackage` to output a binary you can distribute.

In addition, you'll want to see this buildpack if you want to have others run a provided binary *on Heroku*: https://github.com/ph3nx/heroku-binary-buildpack — make sure the binary has been compiled for amd64 Linux if you are targeting Heroku.

Comment: Thanks, so a client of mine could just push to Heroku the binary and the app will be built from this?

Comment: Not quite—they'll need to use a binary buildpack first to tell Heroku what to run as it otherwise expects a Git repo. See this repo for instructions on how to run just a binary: https://github.com/ph3nx/heroku-binary-buildpack